# jQuery not working when trying to use CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to follow the [jQuery tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iRIPJHrdXg) from YouTube to perform the following:

- How to link to the jQuery Framework Tons of ways to target specific elements on a web page
- How to change CSS properties dynamically What is an anonymous function
- How to execute your JQuery code when a page loads

However, the jQuery does not work and I all see is the HTML.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>JQuery Ex 1</title>
<style>
table,th,td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

tr.nice td {
    background: #FAFAD2;
}

tr.mouseon td {
    background: #1E90FF;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("td").css("padding","6px 10 px");
    $(".hero").css("color","red");

})    
</script>

<noscript>
<h3>This site requires JavaScript</h3>
</noscript>
</head>

<body>
<div id="numbers">
    <p>
    <h3>The Most Important Numbers</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Why I Care</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2012</td>
            <td>Year We All Die</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12-21-12</td>
            <td>My Next Birthday</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12-21-12</td>
            <td>The Day We All Die</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>The Most Powerful Superhumans</h3>
    <ul id="superhumans">
        <li class="unknown">Beyonder</li>
        <li class="villian">Galactus</li>
        <li class="hero">Franklin Richards</li>
        <li class="hero">Reed Richards</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
    <h4>Who Do You Think is Most Powerful?</h4>
    </p>
    <h6>Very Small</h6>
</div>
<div>
    <h3 id="randstuff">Stuff 1</h3>
    <h4>Stuff 2</h4>
    <h5>Stuff 3</h5>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you consoled for errors??

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is here**

Incorrect usage of `""` for assigning classes

**Use:**

```
        <li class="villian">Galactus</li>

        <li class="hero">Franklin Richards</li>

        <li class="hero">Reed Richards</li>
```

**Instead of:**

```
        <li class=”villian”>Galactus</li>

        <li class=”hero”>Franklin Richards</li>

        <li class=”hero”>Reed Richards</li>
```

Use `""` correctly

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XNyMj/59/)**

Answer (score 0):

in the document.ready code

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("td").css({"padding":"6px 10 px"});
    $(".hero").css({"color":"red"});
});
```

also a semicolon is missing at end of document.ready

in your html replace

```
<li class="unknown">Beyonder</li>
<li class=”villian”>Galactus</li>
<li class=”hero”>Franklin Richards</li>
<li class=”hero”>Reed Richards</li>
```

with
     Beyonder
     Galactus
     Franklin Richards
     Reed Richards
the problem is the (") in the first li you have inserted it correctly but in other 3 li (”) it is not correct. You need to replace (”) with (") in other 3 li's. I tried it with jsfiddle and it worked.

Comment: This is not at all a problem. we can use `,` while setting a single style.

Comment: Hi, still does not work

Comment: semicolon at end of document.ready was missing please try with it

Comment: Semicolon is also not a problem.!

Comment: tried with semi-colon still does not work

Comment: I have updater the answer I checked it with jsfiddle and this worked i used jquery 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Try using, onready handler `$(document).ready(function(){` or `$(function(){`

```
 $(function(){
    $("td").css({"padding":"6px 10 px"});
    $(".hero").css({"color":"red"});
});
```

instead of

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
    $("td").css("padding","6px 10 px");
    $(".hero").css("color","red");

})
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

In the html code you are making a mistake you have to use "" instead of ””. AS you are using in . To see what is generating in the html see the view source. So use "" and you will see your code is working. There is only syntax problem in the html code.